# Dynamic Spill-Down with INDIRECT

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My goal is to create a table of the value of a single cell across many sheets as a spill-down array.

My current practice is to enter:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet" & ROWS($1:1) & "!A1")
```

and manually copy downwards.  I first tried:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet" & SEQUENCE($Z$100) & "!A1")
```

where **Z100** contains *3*.  This spills-down, but returns *#VALUE!*  So I took a step backwards and tried:

`=INDIRECT("Sheet" & SEQUENCE(3) & "!A1")` which also failed.  I took several steps backward and tried something really simple:

`=INDIRECT("A" & 1)` which works
`=INDIRECT("A" & ROWS($1:1))` which also works, but
`=INDIRECT("A" & SEQUENCE(1))` fails with he same error *(? I have no idea why ?)*.  So:

- Can I make `SEQUENCE()` work within `INDIRECT()` ?
- If not, is there another way to make a dynamic spill-down table of the value across many sheets ?

Comment: INDIRECT does not like array entries: `=INDIRECT({"A1";"A2";"A3"})` will also fail the same way.  One will need vba to get around this.

Comment: Are what you are returning numbers or text?

Comment: @ScottCraner  Thank you ........................I was hoping someone had a magic trick.............

Comment: I might if they are numbers

Comment: @ScottCraner  They **are** numbers.  The idea of a fill-down was to embed the formula in `MIN` or `MAX` or `INDEX`................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output expected is numbers, wrap in SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("Sheet" & SEQUENCE($Z$100) & "!A1"),"<>")
```

[image]

Comment: .......................  **PERFECT!**  ...................................